# How to publish a jar to flatDir with Gradle without "-unspecified" in the name?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project that publishes a jar file to a flatDir repository. 
The publishing works fine, but the uploadArchives task seems to append "-unspecified" to the jar's filename when uploading it. The jar's filename in the build/libs output folder does not have this postfix.

How can I configure the uploadArchives task to skip the appending of "-unspecified" ?

Answer (score 5):

This likely happens because you didn't set `project.version`. Either set it to a version number, or set it to `null`.

Comment: FYI - I construct my version number in an 'ext' block in my gradle file.  Following Peter's suggestion, at the end I added a:

`project.version = myFullVersion`

Comment: I set my project.version=null in my gradle.properties file, but I still the unspecified.